# find the smallest m

Tags: number-theory

Let m be smallest positive integer, which complies with $$n<\sqrt[3]{m}=n+r $$
where n is an positive integer and $0<r<\frac{1}{1000}$. Find m.
In other words do I have to find the smallest positive integer $m$ taken to third root, so it only goes beyond/crosses an integer $n$ with less than $\frac{1}{1000}$. Can I please have some help?

Comment: repost of [this thread](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/972373/find-the-smallest-m-for-which-this-is-possible) (but it was removed)

Comment: Same question, same insufficient wording

Comment: @galois What is that you can't understand?

Comment: @Andersen12 the current question doesn't tell us what we get to pick and what is fixed. While its clear in this case what you mean, most people don't want to go through the work of deciphering what you want so that the problem makes sense.

Comment: If $n = 2$, then there isn't such an integer $m$. (The cube root of 8 is 2, the cube root of 9 is 2.080....).

Comment: @Derek I believe the point is we get to choose $m$ and $n$ and $r$. (Here $r$ is basically useless notation). Obviously $m = n^3 + 1$ is the only solution for a particular $n$ but solutions do not exist for small $n$.

Answer (score 2):

We seek $n^3 < m < (n + 1/1000)^3$, so we only need that $(n + 1/1000)^3 - n^3 > 1$, and then we can find $m$.

This reduces to a quadratic in $n$ which you can use to find the minimum possible integral $n$ for which this holds, and then $m = n^3 + 1$.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I just needs some hints and finally ...